# Kubernetes readness cannot visit service by DNS

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kube-dns

I deploy Elastic Search and Fluentd in same namespace `test`, and write below config to ensure Fluentd can visit Elastic serach:

```
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 5
          httpGet:
            host: elasticsearch-logging
            path: /
            port: 9200
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
```

This didn't work, so I used the whole DNS name, which still failed:

```
Readiness probe failed: Get http://elasticsearch-logging.test.svc.cluster.local:9200/: dial tcp: lookup elasticsearch-logging.test.svc.cluster.local: no such host
```

I removed liveness part and use `curl` in Fluentd pod, that works:

```
root@fluentd-es-2dvmf:/# curl http://elasticsearch-logging:9200/
{
  "name" : "elasticsearch-logging-0",
  "cluster_name" : "skydiscovery-es-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "fr3oSzpHT_qP9HQJ1WygnA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.2.4",
    "build_hash" : "ccec39f",
    "build_date" : "2018-04-12T20:37:28.497551Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Why do they behave differently?

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an unspoken rules about probe, details refer to [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/13815).
It is not related to any wrong settings.

Map pod ip and service name to `/etc/hosts` can work since host can connent to pod ip but can not resolve service name.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your deployment.
 In description we can see "*livenessProbe*" while  in "error section" there is "*Readiness probe*".

From the "**fluentd**" pod (**cluster IP**) perspective both **service name** and **ip address** are known (as you can see performing curl by name or by ip address).

From the **Kubelet** (**node**) perspective (during the "liveness probe") plase use "**service ip address**" instead.
For testing purposes you can add "**service ip address**" and "**service name**" into your known **/etc/hosts** file.
Please share with your results.